# Tooltip in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have created a table with table cells that contain a delete icon-button with a tooltip that would delete the entire row when clicked.
When a user clicks on the `Delete` icon button, the tooltip will remain seen forever.

Now I need a solution for the tooltip to disappear on row deletion.

Table used - `mdtTable`

Here's my example code:

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
    <html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button test-tooltip" aria-label="delete">
      <md-tooltip md-direction="right">Delete</md-tooltip>
      <md-icon style="width: 24px; height: 24px">delete
      </md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please show your code for tooltip?

Comment: Allright, seems legit. However, what did you try so far? Show us some of you're code. If you want help from us, you have to put some effort in you're question.

Comment: <md-button class="md-icon-button test-tooltip" aria-label="delete">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="left">Delete</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon
          md-svg-src="../img/delete.svg"
          style="width: 24px; height: 24px">
        </md-icon>
      </md-button> i have tried using md-autohide also

Comment: would you be able to call a `.blur()` or any other tooltip specific method so you remove the focus from the tooltip before actually removing the row?